# VSCode "search all references" using CLANGD server indexation fails to find #define identifiers in code

Tags: c++, c, clangd

I have a large c/c++ project containing a lot of #define macros defined in headers. VSCode "find all references" find only the definition in header file but not it usage in cpp files.
I am using Visual Studio Code with Clangd extension with a remote server indexation.
The arguments I am using are:

```
--enable-config
--header-insertion=iwyu
--header-insertion-decorators=true
--all-scope-completion
--include-cleaner-stdlib
```

Is there a way to for the indexation of those header containing #define ?
If not can I mix clangd search in VSCode with Ctags technology which works fine with #define macros?

Example

```
MyHeader.hpp

#define MyVariable 3
enum Variables
{ myEnum = 3}
```

```
MyFile1.cpp

func()
{ 
  use MyVariable;
  use Variables::myEnum;
}
```

```
MyFile2.cpp
functwo()
{ 
  use MyVariable;
  use Variables::myEnum;
}
```

If I do the research on MyVariable on the MyHeader.hpp file, it will find only the header file whereas if I do it on myEnum it will find MyHeader.hpp, MyFile1.cpp and MyFile2.cpp

Comment: I don't fully understand the question. Are you performing "search all references" on a macro symbol, and failing to find occurrences? Are you performing the search from the definition of the macro or from a use? Are the missing references in header or cpp files? An example would be helpful.

Comment: Yes exactly. The missing references are in cpp files.

Comment: I just tested this with example code files similar to what you posted, and for me, searching for `MyVariable` in the header files **does** find the references in the cpp files.

So, maybe you're running into an issue relating to a specific code pattern, and need to provide a more specific code example to diagnose it.